# The "connection was reset" when trying to get svn-diff between two revisions in php

Tags: php, svn

I was trying to get svn difference of same file in two revisions.

I referred this http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-diff.php

```
<?php
list($diff, $errors) = svn_diff(
    'http://www.example.com/svnroot/trunk/foo', SVN_REVISION_HEAD,
    'http://www.example.com/svnroot/branches/dev/foo', SVN_REVISION_HEAD
);
if (!$diff) exit;
$contents = '';
while (!feof($diff)) {
  $contents .= fread($diff, 8192);
}
fclose($diff);
fclose($errors);
var_dump($contents);
?>
```

But I always get below error as "connection was reset" when I run this.

[image]

error log is like below,

```
[Wed Jun 15 17:16:53.495806 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1343] AH00051: child pid 1437 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Jun 15 17:16:53.496043 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1343] AH00051: child pid 1438 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Jun 15 17:16:53.496131 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1343] AH00051: child pid 1439 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Jun 15 17:16:53.496166 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1343] AH00051: child pid 1440 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Jun 15 17:16:53.496198 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1343] AH00051: child pid 1441 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Jun 15 17:16:54.498196 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1343] AH00051: child pid 2805 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Comment: Could you post the error logs for this request.

Comment: @skadoosh i posted the error log

Comment: A segfault is typically irreparable with PHP code; it's usually caused by a bug in the underlying C extension. Perhaps you have some version conflict in your installation, and/or the extension was compiled against another PHP version, or something went awry during compilation; something along those lines.